# How do I get a question bank to display with the answers properly corresponding?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Here's the javascript I'm currently working with. I'm currently setting up the actual quiz building portion in the buildQuiz function at the bottom. My timer is working properly, I believe I have everything set up properly, but I'm not too sure how to execute getting everything to work properly?

```
const questionBank = [
    {
        prompt: "What markup language is used for styling webpages?\n(a) HTML\n\ (b) CSS \n (c) Java",
        answer: "b"
    },
    {
        prompt: "What language uses the syntax let and const?\n(a) HTML\n\ (b) CSS \n (c) Javascript",
        answer: "c"
    },
    {
        prompt: "What markup language is used for the skeleton of a webpage?\n(a) CSS\n\ (b) Javascript \n (c) Python \n (d) HTML",
        answer: "d"
    },
];

let startBtn = document.getElementById("start");

let questions = document.getElementById("question");

function timer(){
    let sec = 15;
    let timer = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML='00:'+sec;
        sec--;
        if (sec < 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            questions.innerHTML="Time's Up!";
        } 
        else {
          questions.innerHTML= "";
        }
    }, 1000);
}

startBtn.onclick = function beginQuiz(){
   timer();
   
}
```

Here's my HTML file for reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Code Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Code Quiz</header>
    <div class="quiz-container">
      <button class="btn" id="start">Start</button>
      <p id="question"></p>
      <button class="btns" id="btn-a">A</button>
      <button class="btns" id="btn-b">B</button>
      <button class="btns" id="btn-c">C</button>
    </div>
    <div class="score-container">
        <p id="timer">00:15</p>
        <h1 class="score">Score: 0</h1>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: `to get everything working properly` What's not working? Be descriptive. Have you tried it? What **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: I am trying to get the questionBank to display to the "question" id in the html. I am not sure what concepts to look into to get it to display. I have the prompts, and I have the answers, I just need them to display onto the screen. The timer works perfectly.

Comment: can you separate questions, answer,s and choices?     {
        prompt: "What markup language is used for styling webpages?
        answer: "b",
       choices:{
     a:"HTML",
 b:"CSS",
c:"Java"
     }
    },  if so then you could foreach loop the question bank and display the question and the choices

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Show the questions when the button is clicked.
startBtn.onclick = function beginQuiz(){
      timer();
   
      let questionBankHtml = '<div id="questionBankHtml">';

      questionBank.forEach(function(question) {
            questionBankHtml += `<p id="question">${question.prompt}</p>`
            questionBankHtml += '<button class="btns" id="btn-a">A</button>'
            questionBankHtml += '<button class="btns" id="btn-b">B</button>'
            questionBankHtml += '<button class="btns" id="btn-c">C/button>'

      }); 
      
      questionBankHtml += '</div>';
      document.getElementById("quizBlock").innerHTML = questionBankHtml;
}


HTML

<body>
    <header>Code Quiz</header>
    <div class="quiz-container">
      <div id="quizBlock"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="score-container">
        <p id="timer">00:15</p>
        <h1 class="score">Score: 0</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Be careful with this approach, however.  When clicking buttons A B or C you are going to need a way to determine the proper answer.  Are you posting a form?

Alternatively, I suggest you structure your data like so:

```
const questionBank = [
    {
        id:1,
        prompt: "What markup language is used for styling webpages?",
        choices:{
            a:"HTML",
            b:"CSS",
            c:"Java"
        },
        answer: "b"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        prompt: "What language uses the syntax let and const?",
        choices:{
            a:"HTML",
            b:"CSS",
            c:"Javascript"
        },
        
        answer: "c"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        prompt: "What markup language is used for the skeleton of a webpage?",
        choices:{
            a:"CSS",
            b:"Javascript",
            c:"Python",
            d:"HTML"
        },
        answer: "d"
    },
];
```

With data in this structure, you can use the choices dynamically to display your buttons and check the id of the object against the "answer"

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this approach. Just for clarity and knowledge, what makes the questionBank structure you wrote better? Thanks again!

edit: I'm meaning to ask what I would need to change in order for the id's to lineup with the question

Comment: Multiple reasons:  1,  you have ABC  and ABCD choices. To dynamically populate the buttons you are going to need the data to loop over (not the string or you need a bunch of logic to determine the choices dynamically). 2 When you start to validate if the user is clicking A B or C or D, you are going to want to know "what question" they are clicking ABCD so give each question an ID will help you in saying if they are clicking C on question id  2 then it is correct.  Are you are going to auto validate the answers after the timer or on a "submit" function?